# Flex Layout force to display scrollar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given the following [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayJdxv) how do I make my content items parent to display the vertical scrollbar?

Following a few posts I found I tried setting: `flex: 1 0 auto`, but that didn't work for me. I know I can achieve it by giving the explicit `height/max-height` to my scrollable container but that'd be the last resort as will have to use `calc()` for that.

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/vJxGNe

Comment: Please separate your css from your html, including moving all teh inline css to classes. Using inline isn't favorable and it makes it so much harder to see how the page is being displayed. Very unlikely anyone is going to want to dig through that to try to help unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's exactly what I need please post it as an answer.

Comment: Instead of `flex: 1` use `flex: 1 0 1px`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyWKwx